# Avoid Race Conditions in PHP on Submit: Please do not click submit more than once!

Tags: php

A while back, online apps used to say, "do not click submit more than once." That's gone now, right? How do you guard against that in, say, PHP?

One solution I'm using involves putting a variable in the Session, so you cannot submit to a page more than once every 10 seconds. That way the database work will have completed so the normal checks can take place. Obviously, this feels like a hack and probably is.

**Edit:** Thanks everybody for the Javascript solution. That's fine, but it is a bit of work. 1) It's an input type=image and 2) The submit has to keep firing until the [Spry stuff](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/) says it's okay. This edit is just me complaining, basically, since I imagine that after looking at the Spry stuff I'll be able to figure it out.

**Edit:** Not that anyone will be integrating with the Spry stuff, but here's my final code using Prototype for the document.getElementByid. Comments welcome!

```
function onSubmitClick() {
    var allValid = true;
    var queue = Spry.Widget.Form.onSubmitWidgetQueue; 
    for (var i=0;i<queue.length; i++) {
        if (!queue[i].validate()) {
            allValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allValid) {
        $("theSubmitButton").disabled = true;
        $("form").submit();
    }
}
```

For some reason, the second form submit was necessary...

Comment: 'var allValid = true' and 'for (var i...', to avoid accidental globals.

Comment: you mean to avoid messing up someone else's allValid or i? var will scope it to the in-function scope?

Comment: I see, @bobince. Here's an article on the thing: http://dhtmldev.com/content/view/74/26/. Basically, with var I avoid messing with other variables named allValid and i.

Comment: If you find an answer to your own question, it is generally posted as an answer to your own question rather than editing your question.

Comment: Thanks X-Istence. I'm not answering my own question. I'm responding to the answers.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out why this question attracts *quite* so much spam...

Comment: @Marc, let me know if you figure anything out or open up a Meta question about this topic. I think it's just very popular in Google.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should do both client- and server-side protections.

**Client side** - disable button e.g. by jquery as cletus has described.

**Server side** - put a token in the form. If there are two submissions with the same token, ignore the latter. Using this approach, you are protected against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF).

Comment: Much better than the (current) higher rated answer. I wonder if "ignore the latter" should actually be "don't change any state" since other behaviour, such as a 'success' message, should still occur?

Comment: Thanks. No, why would you display the success page? You should either display error or reload the page with warning message. The rationale is when the submit button is disabled, user is not able to send the request again. If he manages to do it anyway it's because he has js disabled or tries to hack

Comment: Fascinating, I guessed that CSRF might exist but I didn't know what it was called. I also don't know why I didn't see this answer back in March, but thanks!

Comment: Cannot a race condition also exist with server side token validation? i.e. two form submissions 1 millisecond apart with the same token validate before token validation methods are able to change the token?

Comment: @someuser: depends on the design. If for example the server is allowed to only accept one request with particular unique token, the server-side code needs to be properly synchronized

Answer (score 8):

This is an excellent example of what jQuery is useful for (you can do it in any Javascript though).  Add this code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(":submit",this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

And it disables submit buttons once clicked once.

Comment: Yeah, was going to say: do I really need JQuery just to disable a thing that has an id? Always liked that $( thinger, though...

Comment: you can use plain javascript to do it as well, as cletus mentioned

Comment: Yes plain JS can do it too but (imho) jQuery is much more elegant.  For one thing, the above snippet can be in your standard included Javascript file rather than being littered in your HTML and it'll work on any form.

Comment: +1 - A library like jQuery or Prototype will save you heaps of time and will let you add all sorts of interface niceties and "grace notes" to your site in a way that degrades nicely.

Comment: You can actually source JQuery from Google APIs now, so it cuts down on your bandwidth usage, and there's a good chance its been cached on a user's browser if they've been to any Google sites.

Comment: Thanks everybody! In my own defense, the "yeah I was going to say" in my first comment was a response to the fact that Cletus already said what I was going to say. But yes, I'll have to get into one of the Javascript libraries soon...

Comment: never disable button for serious stuff. if the page load is slow, user will stop the page loading and wouldn't be able to continue as the button is disabled. he will then have to reload the page and enter the form paingfully again! -1

Comment: Um, thats exactly when you should disable submit buttons, otherwise they'll just click submit again.

Comment: No, that's exactly why you should not disable any buttons and have the server gracefully handle multiple submits.

Comment: @dusoft you're right but if you use a onDomReady events, you are able to turn on the trick and don't bother people who doesn't load the whole page..

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, you can disable the button.  I like server-side checks better, though - JS may be disabled, user might hit refresh (although if you're properly using POST that will generate a warning), etc.

You can add a timestamp to the form and track it in the session - require the POSTed timestamp be greater than the tracked one.  That will prevent most double-posts without noticeably affecting the UI.

Answer (score 2):

It's also important to note that PHP's default behaviour if it detects the user has "cancelled" the request (by closing the browser, pressing "stop", or perhaps pressing Submit a second time) is to stop executing the script. This is undesirable if you're doing some sort of lengthy transaction. More details [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php).

Comment: No, but the connection might be dropped.

Comment: My question was if you hit stop on a request, does HTTP communicate that?

Comment: @Daniel: it depends on the web browser.

Comment: HTTP runs over TCP, which *can* communicate a connection termination. The browser will *probably* close the TCP connection when you hit Stop.

Answer (score 2):

I would think the best option is to let the PHP script first set a flag in the session array to indicate that it is processing a form. That way a second request can be set to wait until the original request has completed (use a sleep call server side waiting for the flag to clear).

It is important not to interfere too much with the submit button and process, because the nature of the web is one of uncertainty; the user may want to click a second time if no answer has arrived, and you don't want to lose their data. That could occur if the first request is lost and you have disabled their only way to submit (and therefore store) the data.

One cleaner solution is to submit the request, and use javascript to display a message saying 'Processing', so that the user can see that something is happening, but they are not prevented from re-submitting the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree (but most people do not).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to immediately disable the button on click using Javascript.  This obviously relies on javascript being on on the client browser.

The server side trick is better since it will catch race conditions between multiple browser windows if the user is editing the same record twice.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a simple version of this with javascript when I was working with ASP.NET AJAX but it should work in any case where your button has an actual ID.

I take the following steps in the button onclick event:

1. Disable the button that triggered the onclick event
2. Store the button id in a magic variable `closureId` that I can reference later via closure
3. Use the `setTimeout` function to execute a dynamically defined callback after the specified number of milliseconds (5000ms = 5 seconds)
4. In the callback function I can reference the magic `closureId` and re-enable the button after the timeout

Below is a simple HTML button you can throw into a test.html file by itself to play with:

**<input id="btnTest" type="button" value="test" onclick="var closureId=this.id; this.disabled = true; setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(closureId).disabled = false;}, 5000);>**

You should still be doing server-side checks as others have suggested but in my own instance the submit also did a server side validation of business logic. The user would submit their form and then have to wait to see if the business logic on the server-side would actually allow that entry or not. It also helped out during development when I could take my server down and still have the form submission fail decently.

Note I call that `closureId` variable 'magic' because I don't have a firm grasp of how it works--
I just realized that calling `this.id` didn't work because `this` is a reference to the timeout function that is executing the dynamic callback function and doesn't have any sort of DOM id.

I couldn't find any other way to get a reference to the original event (this.this.id doesn't work) but lexical scoping is somehow allowing me to still access the closureId variable as it was defined at the time of the original button click.

Feel free to fix/comment if you know of a better way!

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not a Javascript expert, but I cannot stand code jammed into onX methods... if you move your definition of the closureId to a method, and then pass the this.id TO the method... well, you'll naturally use variables to solve the problem as you did. But you'll see things clearer, though your code may be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I usually disable the submit button after it's pressed. Session throttling is good against direct attacks, but I do not want to mix interface logic where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Well, it's a secondary control, right? I mean, this is not a UI question: if there are two submits for any reason, you want to throttle them. Until you actually control the user's computer...

Comment: It is a UI decision, since allowing that form to be resubmitted is the problem. It's probably also related to the user not getting enough feedback that something is processing - again a UI failure.

Comment: Not sure what I think yet... I do think you're getting into the user's head and assuming he or she is logical, which is not the case. On the other hand, you have to assume the UI is functioning...

Comment: It's not logical - it's natural. If you don't give the user feedback, he will wonder if he the form was sent or not - causing him to try to submit again. Usually a problem with slow connections and latency.

Comment: True Eran, you're right about this UI case. If the UI is not designed correctly, a user SHOULD click again, which is not what we want.