# Disallowing POST BACK when one is already in progress

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

Disable a post back from asp.net i.e. buttons, links, gridview page index changing and sorting etc when a post back is already in progress. Target browser is IE 6+. I've written these 2 javascript I am not sure how to apply it on GridView Page Index changing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          //isFormSubmitted variable is used to prevent the form submission while the server execution is in progress
          var isFormSubmitted = false;
          //If the form is already submitted, this function will return false preventing the form submission again.
          function SubmitForm(msg)
          {
            try {
             if(isFormSubmitted == true)
             {
               alert('A post back is already in progress. Please wait');
               return false; 
             }
             else 
             {
               var res = false;
               if (msg)
               {
                 res = confirm(msg);
               }
               if (res == true)
               {  
                 isFormSubmitted = true;
               }
               return res;
             }
           } catch(ex) {}
          }

          function VerifySubmit()
          {
             if(isFormSubmitted == true)
             {
               alert('A post back is already in progress. Please wait');
               return false; 
             }
             else 
             {
               isFormSubmitted = true;
               return true;
             }
          } 
</script>
```

For buttons I can attach the SubmitForm to OnClientClick like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" OnClientClick="return SubmitForm('Do you want to continue with cancelling recent action?');" />
```

But I am not sure how to attach the VerifySubmit to non prompting controls like gridview pager.

Comment: Is it that, you want to reduce the possibility of a secondary post being made after a button has been pressed? Something like this:
http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/02/aspnet-double-postback-bug-strikes.html

Comment: Not to disable the post back I need to disallow another attempt of post back when one post back is still in progress. I've a web page which performs a sort of bulk import of around 10 thousands records from an excel file to a CRM system. I show the record on grid and then when user presses Process I'll process the records on server and in the end show the results on the same grid. But during the processing I don't want user to click on a say link (i.e. GridView PageIndex or any other button). So basically I want user to wait before one PostBack is finished.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid Race Conditions in PHP on Submit: Please do not click submit more than once!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414835/avoid-race-conditions-in-php-on-submit-please-do-not-click-submit-more-than-once)

Comment: All the solutions are valid if I know which control is doing the post back. Lets say I've some dynamic controls so I don't know during design time which control will be initiating the post back...

Comment: I've found it handy to serve up a unique request ID and submit that back as part of the post back.  If the server sees the same ID twice, it ignores that post back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 onclick="this.disabled=true;"
```

on your submit-button(s) is all the javascript "magic" you need

When [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is an option you can use this small script to disable all submit-buttons:

```
// Find ALL <form> tags on your page
$('form').submit(function(){
    // On submit disable its submit button
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Found here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit.html

Or you can block the whole page: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#page

Comment: this will disable the current control but user can still post back from other controls or link such as clicking on the GridView PageIndex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable post back set `autopastback=false` for buttons links.
Otherwise you need to give us more information and better instructions / details to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you're doing ajaxy type stuff here and you have an async-postback going and you don't want the user to click a button at that time.

If that is the case then try the following code:

```
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(startRequest);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest);

    function startRequest(sender, e) {
        //disable search button during the AJAX call
        document.getElementById('<%=btnSearch.ClientID%>').disabled = true;

    }

    function endRequest(sender, e) {
        //re-enable the search button once the AJAX call has completed
        document.getElementById('<%=btnSearch.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: ok but how to do it for the Pager for GridView.. I need to disable the GridView and all the links... i.e. links in Column Name for sorting and the PagerIndexes shown for GridView... Got my point?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found is that..

```
//In the head section define this script...

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowProcessingMsg(confirmMsg) {
        var resp = confrim(confirmMsg);
        try {
          if (resp == true) {
            var divC = document.getElementById('<%= divControls.ClientID %>');
            var divM = document.getElementById('<%= divProcessingMsg.ClientID %>');
            if (divC && divM) {
              divC.display = "none";
              divM.display = "block";
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
        } catch (exp) { alert(exp); return false; }
        return resp;
      }
    </script>

//This div will show during processing since by default it's display is none when after
//Post back your page loaded again this will not be diplayed. We are going to set it's
//diplay attribute to block from javascript.

<div id="divProcessingMsg" runat="server" display="none" z-index="1000" />
   <b>Processing.... Please wait.</b>
</div>


//We will hide this div from script by setting its display attribute to none. Since 
//by default this attribute is block when the page loaded again it'll be displayed by 
//default. So no special handling for setting display again to block is required.

<div id="divControls" runat="server" display="block" z-index="1" />
   <asp:GridView ............ >
   .....
   .....
   .....
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnProcess" Text="Process" OnClientClick="return ShowProcessingMsg('Do you want to continue with processing'); OnClick="btnProcess_ServerClick" />
</div>
```